# fetch data using jQuery from external JSON site, Singleton class

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, singleton, fetch

I am being trained and my task is to fetch data using jQuery from external JSON site. I am using a Singleton class to do so. The data will be fetched from [this site](http://freegeoip.net/json/) during initialization and data will be added to the class as attributes. As a hint I was told to use the callback functionality to ensure that the data is being fetched. This [link](http://pastie.org/8430516) shows what I figured out so far. I run this script on html (loaded jquery) and I get no results. I am not sure if my jQuery code is correct.

Any kind of advice/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of examples of using jquery to access an api over http.  One example would be:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    });
    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

What problem are you solving by using a Singleton?  Why do you need to enforce a single instance of a class?

Comment: I was asked to. It's a task.
Thanks for adding the example. I tried it before along with others with no results. i got results now. thanks I will take it from here!

Answer (score 1):

Your script is working, problem is that the alert is outside of the ajax success callback so you dont see it.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: feedurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'data',
            success: function(data) {
                object = data;
            } 
        });     alert(object);
```

This should be :

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: feedurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'data',
            success: function(data) {
                object = data;
                    alert(object); 
            } 
        });
```

For info, you can do the same thing with only :

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I moved the alert into jquery segment. I still get the alert window with [object Object]. Is this expected? I thought I was going to get the string from that json site. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. Use `console.log(object)` to see the content of `object` in the developper console (F12 to activate it)